# Android Firebase(11.0.2) not saving data to Firebase on Mobile-Lock

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement code that tracks friends using the following methodology:

1. Friend location is pushed to Firebase (continuously every 1 second).
   *-->(Sender)*.
2. Location is pulled in my device and displayed using Google Maps API 
   *--> (Receiver)*.

**Issue-Description:**

When i **lock my phone**,  after some time(approx 5 minutes) my app is **unable to push data to firebase-server**(datbaseRef.setValue()).and it again started pushing when i open my lock.Please suggest some idea how to make firebase to push(Save) data continusoulsy to database(datbaseRef.setValue()) even with Mobile Lock.

**Extra-Info:**

Even i have tried acquiring  "***PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK***" but still of no use.

Comment: are activation some kind of saving data or batteries saving mode

Comment: Thanks Oussema you were right, My mobile battery saving mode was ON, which was stopping background applications. After making it OFF my problem solved. Thanks